# Transparent Redis Dal with serviceStack Redis

Tags: redis, servicestack

Yeap I'm here with another weird question:)

I try to implement transparent Redis Data Access Layer.

I will load N*1 and 1*1 relations Eagerly, N*N and 1*N relations Lazily.

```
public class User
{
   public long CityId {get;set;} 

   [EagerLoading]
   [IgnoreDataMember]
   public City {get;set;}
}

public class City
{
  public ICollection<long> UserIds {get;set;}

  [LazyLoading]
  [IgnoreDataMember] 
  public ICollection<User> Users{get;set;}
}
```

There is no problem with CUD operations (Create,Update,Delete). I can store full object hierarchy.

But  I need non-typed Get method for retrieving objects.

```
public class GenericRedisRepository
{
     public object Get(string objectUrn)
     {
        using (var r = RedisManager.GetReadOnlyClient())
        {
            var pocoObject=r.GetObject(objectUrn); // I COULD NOT FIND THIS METHOD
            foreach (var property in ReflectionHelper.GetEagerLoadingProperties(pocoObject))
            {
                // Fixup relations and load all EagerLoading properties recursively
            } 
        }
     }
}
```

Any idea or alternative way..

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for being late. I wonder why you stick to having properties rather than methods that are not serialized/deserialized by nature:

```cs
public class User
{
   public long Id { get; set; }
}

public class City
{
  public IEnumerable<long> UserIds { get; set; }

  public IEnumerable<User> GetUsers()
  {
      using (var userData = redis.As<User>())
          return userData.GetByIds(UserIds);
  }
}
```

This way you can defer loading users by calling `GetUsers()` when you really need them:

```cs
var city = redis.As<City>().GetById(id);
...
var users = city.GetUsers();
```